# Javascript jQuery strip leading and trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

I want to trim the value (strip leading and trailing spaces) and make first letter in every word capital. When user leave from the element (blur event)

HTML input as follows

```
<input id="iptFirstName" name="iptFirstName" type="text"/>
```

JS  piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     var iptFirstName = $("#iptFirstName");
     iptFirstName.blur(validateForename);
});


function validateForename(){
    var firstName= $("#iptFirstName").val;
    //strip leading and trailing spaces
    firstName= $.trim(firstName)
    //change first letter in every word to uppercase
    firstName= Capital(firstName);
    //update input field whit new value
    $("#iptFirstName").val(firstName);
}

function Capital(eleValue) {
    var eleValue;

    if (eleValue != "") {
        var firstLetter = eleValue.substring(0, 1).touppercase();
        var restOfWord = eleValue.substring(1, eleValue.length).tolowercase();
        eleValue = firstLetter + restOfWord;
        return eleValue;
    } 
}
```

Please understand why it isn't working or maybe have a better approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     var iptFirstName = $("#iptFirstName");
     iptFirstName.blur(validateForename);
});


function validateForename(){
    var firstName= $("#iptFirstName").val();
    //strip leading and trailing spaces
    firstName= $.trim(firstName)
    //change first letter in every word to uppercase
    firstName= Capital(firstName);
    //update input field whit new value
    $("#iptFirstName").val(firstName);
}

function Capital(eleValue) {
    var eleValue;

    if (eleValue != "") {
        var firstLetter = eleValue.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        var restOfWord = eleValue.substring(1, eleValue.length).toLowerCase();
        eleValue = firstLetter + restOfWord;
        return eleValue;
    } 
}
```

try this must work, only few changes done,

```
var firstName= $("#iptFirstName").val;
```

to

```
var firstName= $("#iptFirstName").val();

touppercase
```

to

```
toUpperCase

tolowercase
```

yo

```
toLowerCase
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iptFirstName = $("#iptFirstName");
    iptFirstName.blur(function() {
        $(this).val(function() {
            return $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/(^[a-z]| [a-z])/g, function($0) {
                return $0.toUpperCase();
            })
        })
    });
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/QvATH/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, in your code capitalized only the first letter, but if there another word after the space, it won’t capital.

Comment: Sorry about that - probably a bit late now but answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `$.trim(firstName).replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {return $1.toUpperCase();})`

Answer (score 0):

You had several errors trought the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#iptFirstName").blur(validateForename);
});


function validateForename(){
    var firstName= $("#iptFirstName").val();
    //strip leading and trailing spaces
    firstName= $.trim(firstName);
    //change first letter in every word to uppercase
    firstName= Capital(firstName);      
    //update input field whit new value
    $("#iptFirstName").val(firstName);
}

function Capital(eleValue) {
    if (eleValue != "") {
        var firstLetter = eleValue.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        var restOfWord = eleValue.substring(1, eleValue.length).toLowerCase();
        eleValue = firstLetter + restOfWord;
    }
    return eleValue;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3XhL/

Comment: Yes there were some JS case sensitive issues. Thanks.